# scanf using a %f for an integer

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, scanf

I am trying to parse a string that has some numbers seperated by a space. However, these numbers could be integers or floats. Is there  a way in scanf to parse both integers and numbers as one collective float?

For example:

```
float arg1, arg2 = 0;
sscanf("LINE 10 10", "LINE %f %f", &arg1, &arg2);

// and
sscanf("LINE 10.0 10.0", "LINE %f %f", &arg1, &arg2);
```

Comment: Surely the first `sscanf` line is perfectly fine and will work as expected?

Comment: Both examples should work OK - what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: since any integer is also a float number there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: you mean , you want to handle both float & integer in same way..

Comment: I thought %f only counts as float and will not parse an integer?

Comment: Did You ask these because it came to your mind without trying the syntax :) Please dont waste SO memory with simple questions :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just works, integers are special cases of floating points.

Note, however, that large integers might not be able to be represented precisely by floats (eg. `1e9 + 1`), but I don't think you bother about that.

Comment: Indeed. To lessen the severity of this problem, OP should be using `double` and not `float`. Basically `float` should never be used unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out my tests were wrong, you can read from an integer with %f.